Result Curl\json in to table with multilne
I have a result from curl where generate more and more line.. I try to put in 1 line for decode with json but I have more of 65000 crt and not decode it

if I insert all in 1 line
    select distinct
'{'+STUFF((SELECT '' + output
          FROM #output
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as riga
into #output2
from #output

select * from #output2

I have 1 line with 65536 max...
I want decode it with json how I can to do?
